# How to find the geographical direction to which the mobile is facing accurately

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, gyroscope, compass

How do we find the geographical direction to which the mobile is facing accurately, like north, east, south, west. Though i can use mobile sensors like compass, accelerometer, gyro, the values are not accurate. When i tilt my mobile to different orientation, the compass is not able to show the “North” all the time, it deviates a lot from actual direction. Hence not able to find the right direction. How can i calibrate the sensor values so that i can detect the directions accurately irrespective of mobile orientation.

Thanks.

Comment: Since your sensors are too inaccurate, depending on your usage, on which you didn't elaborate, you could use two gps coordinates and calculate the vector. That way you would have a direction in which the device is moving. This will only work if your device is moving though.

Comment: Using two gps coordinates and calculating the vector can give the direction of my device. But i need to find in which direction my mobile screen is facing, even the device is static.

Comment: the location object does has a bearing value which can tell the heading!